# NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString isFileURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x712e450'

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5, ios4

I am new to iPhone App development.

When I run a sample project, I did which parses an `xml` feed and displays the contents along with image in a table view, I get this error -

```
"NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString isFileURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x712e450'"
```

It is occurring only when I try to display the image in `UITableViewCell`.

The code I used for getting images from `url` is -

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:IMAGE])
{
    NSURL *imageUrl = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];
    bbc.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];        
}
```

where `bbc` is a `class(NSObject subclass)` object used to store the parsed contents.

Comment: balakrishna ningalith enth veruppikkalado?

Comment: onn poyi chathoode..?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think you are using `NSString` as `NSURL`. Try this:

```
    NSURL *imageUrl =[NSURL URLWithString:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like "url" is in fact an `NSString`, not an `NSURL` object.  Convert it to an `NSURL` object yourself:

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:IMAGE])
{
    NSString *urlStr = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"];
    NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];
    bbc.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

imageURL is not a NSURL, but a string.

Comment: yep. it is , i didnt notice it since the compiler didnt show me any warningsat that point.. Thanks any way

Comment: ya, i got it,  [attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"] returns a string which i assigned to an NSURL object.